# Thread-safe database updates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, task-parallel-library

I have the following method that will return VariantID for given VariantName ("Name" in db).
To avoid calling my db few thousand times I have dumped all records (~30) to the simple dictionary.

I'm almost certain that this is the correct way of implementing this method but I would like to hear some feedback and any possible tips.

TestManagementEntities is an EntityFramework DbContext

Calling Method

```
private void UpdateVariants(WorkItem workItem, string variantValue, TestManagementEntities db)
    {           

        string[] variants = variantValue.Split(',').Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();

        int[] variantIds = new int[variants.Count()];

        Dictionary<string, int> variantDictionary =
            db.Variants.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, y => y.VariantID);
        Object lockObject = new Object();

        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, variants.Count(), i =>
        {
            variants[i] = variants[i].Trim();
            //Method in question call
            variantIds[i] = GetVariantId(variants[i], variantDictionary, db, lockObject);
        });

        //Some not relevant to question code here
    }

private int GetVariantId(string variantName, Dictionary<string, int> variantDictionary, TestManagementEntities db, Object lockObject)
    {
        if (variantDictionary.ContainsKey(variantName))
        {
            return variantDictionary[variantName];
        }
        else
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                if (variantDictionary.ContainsKey(variantName))
                {
                    return variantDictionary[variantName];
                }
                else
                {
                    Variant newVariant = new Variant();
                    newVariant.Name = variantName;
                    db.Variants.Add(newVariant);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    variantDictionary.Add(variantName, newVariant.VariantID);
                    return newVariant.VariantID;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Why is your parameter `variantValue` a `string`? Why not an `IEnumerable<string>` or an `ICollection<string>` or something like that?

---

<s>Why is `variants` an `array`? If it had been an `ICollection<string>` it would have had a `Count` property that was far less costly than `.Count()`.</s> Don't use the [(extension) method `.Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338038(v=vs.100).aspx), use the `Length` property. Also: why is it called `variants` when it really contains names?

---

Why do you do this inside that loop: `variants[i] = variants[i].Trim();`? Why not do this when you do `variantValue.Split(',').Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();`

---

The whole logic seems really contrived to me: storing the contents of a table in a dictionary, just to check whether you need to add a value to the DB and to retrieve the IDs? Why not make it much more simple:

- Query the DB for the entries where the name corresponds with the ones you've received as a parameter (a [WHERE IN query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024201/how-to-use-the-in-operator-in-linq)).
- Remove the results from the list of names.
- Loop through the filtered names, create a `Variant` for each and only execute `db.SaveChanges();` after you've added ALL items.
- After you've executed `db.SaveChanges();` all those newly created variants will have an `ID` which you can retrieve.

By the way, don't do ContainsKey if you need the value associated with said key, instead use [`TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx).

---

I suppose that you need `variantIds` for that `//Some not relevant to question code here`, and that bothers me a bit. `GetVariantId` for instance does far more than the method name says it does, and thus I suspect `UpdateVariants` contains more logic that really shouldn't be there according to the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7591887/648075).

Comment: @RobH D'oh, confused it with `IEnumerable<T>`. Fixed it.